# Click and unclick with jquery

Tags: jquery, click

When you click in a `div class="in"` I want to add a `span` inside the `div class="in"` and add `background-color`.

When I click on an element that's outside `div class = "in"` I want to remove the added `span` and the css.

How to do it?

Comment: Do you have some code of your tryouts?

Comment: post your code what you try. and use jsfiddle

Comment: I don't have code. Until now I have used jQuery function .click(), but it doesn't work on "unclick"

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
$(".in").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
    var span = $("<span>My new span</span>").css('background-color', 'yellow');
    $(this).append(span);
}); 
$(".outer").click(function(event){
    $(this).find('.in span').remove();
});
```

Have a look at the example http://jsfiddle.net/vA2FP/1/

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this with fewer lines of code:

*Clicking on div with class `.in`*

```
$(".in").on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('<span/>').appendTo($(this)).text("new Added").css({'background-color':'Red'});
});
```

*Clicking out side the Div:*

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
   $(".in").find('span').remove(); 
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/44vMD/)